# How to align text according to button above?

Tags: html, css, alignment

How to align item's price above the button in this case?

```
.price-label{
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
}

.add-to-cart-btn{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-100px;
    left:50%;
    width:200px;
    bottom:10px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: can you add your html and a screenshot of what you want to achieve ? ( do you want them to be all like the middle one ? )

Comment: https://github.com/archeski/bookstore/blob/master/templates/landing/home.html

Comment: image is on top of this question, with bad link "enter image description here"

Comment: do you want the left one and the right one to be aligned right above the `add  to cart` like the middle one ?

Comment: @Taki Yes, correct. Maybe with few pixels spacing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fix the height of the paragraph above it (change it according to your need ):

```
<p style="height:200px">
    {{ image.item.short_description|truncatechars_html:300 }}
</p>
```

or you can do it in **css**

Comment: doesn't help...

Comment: it doesn't have to be `200px` , try a bigger value

Comment: it's not working at all

Comment: Sorry about that :/ , you can try adding  `bottom: 100px;` to `.price-label` since it has a relative position